# How to fix specific div's position in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to fix position of my divs like this:
[image]

so I did this code (note that div's order in HTML is reverse)

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="area">
        <div id="bottom">bottom</div>
        <div id="middle">middle</div>
        <div id="top">top</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css code (colors aren't important)

```
#area{
    position:fixed;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    padding: 10px;
}
#bottom{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#middle{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
#top{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    bottom: 60px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Why all divs inside **#area** are on top of **#area**?
[Code example](http://jsfiddle.net/xabbwrct/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position:relative` refers to relative to the object's **own** visual position, since each element is (apparently) 30px tall, the top and bottom items need to move 60px in a respective direction.

If the elements' sizes are not known an alternative solution is recommended.

```css
#area {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}
#bottom {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  top: 60px;
  /* up 60px from where it is */
  position: relative;
}
#middle {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  /* no need to move*/
}
#top {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  top: -60px;
  /* down 60px from where it is */
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="area">
    <div id="bottom">bottom</div>
    <div id="middle">middle</div>
    <div id="top">top</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Alternative Solution with Flexbox** : No need for any positioning.

```
#area{
    position:fixed;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column-reverse;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```css
#area{
    position:fixed;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column-reverse;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    padding: 10px;
}
#bottom{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
#middle{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
 }
#top{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;

}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div id="area">
        <div id="bottom">bottom</div>
        <div id="middle">middle</div>
        <div id="top">top</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because top, left, bottom, right work differently basing on the position you are using:

- `position: static`: they are ignored
- `position: relative`: **relative to the original element's position** in the flow
- `position: absolute` : relative to the first absolute/relative parent
- `position: fixed`: relative to the viewport (visible area)

Read more on [this great article](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/).

Then in your case just [put the divs in the right order in the HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/xabbwrct/6/) and remove the bottom positioning, or [play with the positioning](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/xabbwrct/7/) to re-invert them with CSS (but it's unclear why you should do that).

Answer (score 0):

Because you are setting a size to bottom in a relative element..remove it and add `top` for best practice.

**CSS**

```
    #area{
    position:fixed;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    padding: 10px;
}
#bottom{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    top: 60px;
    position: relative;
}
#middle{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: relative;
}
#top{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    top: -60px;
    position: relative;
}
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/xabbwrct/5/)**

Answer (score -1):

Simple fix, simply remove `position` and `bottom` properties, there you go:

```css
#area{
    position:fixed;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    padding: 10px;
}
#bottom{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    display: block;
}
#middle{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: block;
}
#top{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div id="area">
        <div id="bottom">bottom</div>
        <div id="middle">middle</div>
        <div id="top">top</div>
    </div>
</div>
```